# Javascript: mapping over an array and sorting the return array depending on a lookup object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I would like to map over an array and sort it depending on an lookup object.

```
const obj = {
  "email": {position: 1, name: "email"},
  "firstname": {position: 2, name: "firstname"},
  "lastname": {position: 3, name: "lastname"}
}

const arr = ["lastname", "email", "firstname"];

expected output: ["email", "firstname", "lastname"];
```

I know that I must use the map function in order to return a new array.
I can get an new array with the full or object or retrieving only a array with all names or position properties.
But I cannot figure out how to sort them.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

`Array.sort` function accepts a callback (sorter) function that will return comparison of any two items in array. So just need to compare their position (of 2 items in array). This is done by substracting them to get a positive/0/negative result.

```js
const obj = {
  "email": {position: 1, name: "email"},
  "firstname": {position: 2, name: "firstname"},
  "lastname": {position: 3, name: "lastname"}
}

const arr = ["lastname", "email", "firstname"];

// expected output: ["email", "firstname", "lastname"];
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return obj[a].position - obj[b].position
})

console.log(arr)
```