Custom Sort Compare Function To Put Specific Value On Top
I have an array of objects.
let wins = Display.get_tab_list(Meta.TabList.NORMAL, null);

I want to sort the array based on it's object's property wm_class so that objects with wm_class Fsearch will come first. objects with wm_class VSCodium will come second. objects with wm_class firefox will come third. Rest of the windows afterwards. No need to sort those (Rest of the windows). how would the compare function look like, so that I can run myArray.sort(compareFunction)?
I tried:
const classOrder = {
    "Fsearch": 0,
    "VSCodium": 1,
    "firefox": 2
};

wins.sort((winA, winB) => {
    let orderA = classOrder[winA.wm_class] || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    let orderB = classOrder[winB.wm_class] || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    return orderA - orderB;
});

but not giving the expected result.
Update:
The code that is working for me is:
const classOrder = {
    "Fsearch": 1,
    "VSCodium": 2,
    "firefox": 3
};

wins.sort((winA, winB) => {
    let orderA = classOrder[winA.wm_class] || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    let orderB = classOrder[winB.wm_class] || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    // If both windows belong to the same class, sort based on user time
    if (orderA === orderB) {
        let userTimeA = winA.get_user_time();
        let userTimeB = winB.get_user_time();
        return userTimeB - userTimeA; // Sort in descending order of user time
    }
    return orderA - orderB;
});

I am not putting it in the answer section because i found it by tinkering. Not sure why 1,2,3 works. And also added a secondary sort using get_user_time(). This returns unix timestamp. So the idea is, after putting expected classes on top i want to re-sort the objects based on timestamp.
P.S. Any reference to reading material about this will be also helpful.

You should be using ?? instead of || in your comparator function. Or else change those ordering values to 1, 2, and 3.  The value 0 tests as false.

Also because you give the non-special entries the sort key of Infinity, they'll end up in either random order or else the original order.

Oh also, don't use Infinity, as Infinity - Infinity is NaN.  Use Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER or something. Or 1000.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901507/0-with-operator and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321611/javascript-mapping-over-an-array-and-sorting-the-return-array-depending-on-a-lo, this is probably a duplicate of those.

0 || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

@AhmadIsmail - "Not sure why 1,2,3 works." For the reason Pointy gave you right after you posted the question.
